# Azure CLI - Query Power state of a virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I would love to query VMs powerstate with azure cli in bash

Mine goal is to stop a virtual machine, but before that check if the machine was already stopped and vise versa.

So I need to get the powerstate of a specific VM, but I don't see az vm list have that as a parameter. How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

To check Power state of the Azure Virtual Machine, please use the below command:

```
az vm show -g ResourceGroupName -n testvm -d --query powerState
```

[image]

The command will give the status of the specific Azure VM. And based on that you can Start/Stop the Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy to do just  ---query and powerstate :D. After reading this whole documentation. How did u find it

Answer (score 2):

Where is the issue to just try to stop the VM regardless of the state?
Adding a check for the state just adds additional processing time for the script.

However, `az vm list -d -o table` should give you what you are looking for.
You could also query for the state directly `az vm list -d --query "[?powerState=='VM running']" -o table`

The `-d` or `--show-details` parameter will add the additional details you are looking for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using Az VM start or stop if they are already stopped or started, so I need to use az vm list, but query only specific VM and check it's status. Your command here will give me a powerstate for all vms. I only need to see for a one machine specific

Comment: You can also limit the output. az vm show --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyVm --show-details